# Airflow: Package installation of rpy2 to execute RScripts in Airflow

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, setuptools, docker-image

**Requirement:** To be able to install the rpy2 library, as the code to be orchestrated with airflow uses it extensively

**Current Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential r-base r-base-core r-cran-randomforest python3.6 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev&& \
   rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip==20.0.2 wheel==0.34.2 setuptools==49.6.0

RUN python3 -m pip install rpy2

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('data.table')"

COPY . /app
```

**Issue:** I'm having issues surrounding the necessary libraries, which didn't come up in the code itself.

**The Error:**

```
[6/8] RUN python3 -m pip install rpy2:
1.176 Collecting rpy2
1.304   Downloading rpy2-3.5.14.tar.gz (219 kB)
1.422   Installing build dependencies: started
4.186   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
4.187   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
4.225   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
4.225   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
4.225    command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpff4u1mul
4.225        cwd: /tmp/pip-install-12iwr626/rpy2
4.225   Complete output (31 lines):
4.225   Traceback (most recent call last):
4.225     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 257, in <module>
4.225       main()
4.225     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 240, in main
4.225       json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
4.225     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 85, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
4.225       backend = _build_backend()
4.225     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 63, in _build_backend
4.225       obj = import_module(mod_path)
4.225     File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
4.225       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
4.225     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
4.225       import distutils.core
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1002, in _find_and_load_unlocked
4.225     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 945, in _find_spec
4.225     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 72, in find_spec
4.225       return self.get_distutils_spec()
4.225     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 77, in get_distutils_spec
4.225       class DistutilsLoader(importlib.util.abc.Loader):
4.225   AttributeError: module 'importlib.util' has no attribute 'abc'
```

Comment: For what I could figure out googling and looking at [setuptools github](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/2361), there were issues supporting Python 3.10 in older releases of `setuptools`. Have you tried installing a later version of setuptools (something equal or newer than version `50.0.2`) rather than the `49.6.0` you're installing?

Comment: I will try that now, I have not tried that.

Comment: @Savir I tried it and now I receive the Error:
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.command.build'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these errors tend to be issues with different package versions fighting each other. For instance: a package removed a method or moved some functions around in its latest release, and another package that depends on the former is not aware (yet) of those changes.

As in: Package A uses Package B's `.do_something` method, but Package B's developers rename it to `.do_something_better`. If you have the latest version of B, but an old version of A which is not yet aware of the rename... well... it will crash (as you've seen)

That seems to be what's happening with Python 3.10 and setuptools quite a bit.

TL;DR: you're seeing a quite common (and pesky) versioning issue.

This said, this Dockerfile is successfully building:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential \
    r-base r-base-core r-cran-randomforest \
    libinput-dev libgbm-dev liblzma-dev libbz2-dev libicu-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev \
    python3.6 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev&& \
   rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools>51

RUN python3 -m pip install rpy2

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('data.table')"

COPY . /app
```

Notice there's a bunch of `-dev` packages required and that I allowed pip, wheel and setuptools to be a bit more loose when it comes to versions. Also, since I don't have your `requirements.txt` file, I had to left it blank.

**HOWEVER**: You are fetching the `:latest` Ubuntu image. As of October 2023 that means installing Ubuntu 22.04 (codename "Jammy Jellyfish"). The default Python 3 in that image is intended to be [3.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/python/python3) yet you seem to be installing Python 3.6. This can lead to potential issues, since if you do some `apt-get install some_python_package`, you could *potentially* end up with Python 3.6 in your system, yet a version of `some_python_package` intended for Python 3.10, which is not great.

If you'd rather use Python 3.6, may I suggest you base your Dockerfile on one of the Python Docker images?

For instance, [`python:3.6.14-bullseye`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/python/3.6.14-bullseye/images/sha256-215ef6ca659b78f12df01e83f11fd22d4bfac7eed75f4438e84b1b90686f3cae?context=explore), which is Debian (not Ubuntu) based but contains some tweaks and environment variables geared towards providing a safe environment (or "ecosystem") for Python 3.6

```
FROM python:3.6.14-bullseye

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential \
    r-base r-base-core r-cran-randomforest \
    libinput-dev libgbm-dev liblzma-dev libbz2-dev libicu-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev \
   && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools

RUN python3 -m pip install rpy2

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('data.table')"

COPY . /app
```

There are quite a bit more Python Docker images with slightly different features and contents. You might wanna take a look [at this article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/) and see which one best fits your needs.

Pinning an image to a specific version, rather than to `:latest` has also the advantage that if (for instance) the Ubuntu Docker image maintainers decide to update what *"latest"* means from the current 22.04 to, let's say 24.04, your won't be bitten by an unexpected full O.S. upgrade.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I accepted it as the answer. I see, yes I had seen while searching the issue online that there were lots of posts on issues with the versioning there. But how did you know which to include to fix it? I'm very greatful for both your corrected anwer and the second suggestion. I've modified the FROM in the Dockerfile in accordance to your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry I edit a lot . I guess, to answer your question... I've seen these issues before (a lot of times) so the least version number you specify, the better (usually). As for what libraries to include... Well: I just built the image, waiting for errors like`ld: can not find lbz2` (which are pretty much always caused by `-dev` files missing), googling the error message to see which `-dev` package provides it (check [this](http://wei48221.blogspot.com/2017/08/linux-how-to-solve-problem-of-usrbinld.html) out), adding it to `apt-get install...` repeat the process until no more errors happen. 

Comment: Thank you! I see, I'll try to incorporate that method too!

Comment: Glad I was able to help, @moltke_colombia . Have fun coding! 